# Interesting questions on android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I miss the interesting questions view on the android app a lot. This is the view I use almost all the time on the desktop version of the app and I believe it is great.

I know there is a view "unanswered my tags" but the interesting questions view also provides view for questions that already have some answers. Also interesting questions view is able to show questions that are not only for tags you've marked as favorite but for somewhat related questions. Please add logic for this view in the android app.